# Necesito ayuda con problema de numeros mayores

Tags: java, bucle-for, bucles, scanner

necesito ayuda con este enunciado:

> Dados 5 números, indicar cuál es el mayor.

No sé cómo hacerlo para numeros mayores de 3, soy nuevo programando y me gustaria solucionar este problema seria de gran ayuda, voy aqui pero no puedo hacerlo en mas de 3 por que no sé que colocar.

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n1, n2, n3;
        System.out.print("Introduzca primer número: ");
        n1 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Introduzca segundo número: ");
        n2 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Introduzca tercer número: ");
        n3 = sc.nextInt();
        if (n1 > n2) {
            if (n1 > n3) {
                System.out.println("El mayor es: " + n1);                                             
            } else {
                System.out.println("el mayor es: " + n3);     
            }
        } else if (n2 > n3) {
            System.out.println("el mayor es: " + n2);
        } else {
            System.out.println("el mayor es: " + n3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿ _Mayores de tres_  o _más de tres números_? Si es para más de tres números, la sugerencia es que revises cómo usar arreglos (o un ArrayList, idealmente), los pongas todos ahí y vayas viendo cuál es el mayor.

Comment: Y recorres el array con un `for`

Comment: Hola, aprovecha la oportunidad para consultar **algoritmo de la burbuja** aprenderás un montón y como solución ofreces los del extremo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si los números se van ingresando de forma secuencial se puede ir eligiendo el mayor según se van ingresando y de paso se pueden pedir por adelantado cuantos números se quieren leer:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Numeros {
    
    int mayor = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int menor = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        Numeros n = new Numeros();
        n.procesarNumeros();
    }
    
    private void procesarNumeros(){
        
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.printf("Introduzca la cantidad de números a leer: ");
        
        int numerosALeer = sc.nextInt();
        
        for(int i = 1; i <= numerosALeer; i++){
            
            System.out.printf("Introduzca el número %d: ",i);
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            establecerNumeroMayor(n);
            establecerNumeroMenor(n);
        }
        
        System.out.println("el mayor es " + mayor);
        System.out.println("el menor es " + menor);
        
    }
    
    private void establecerNumeroMayor(int n){
        if(n > mayor) mayor = n;
    }
    private void establecerNumeroMenor(int n){
        if(n < menor) menor = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: oye bro, una pregunta y si quiero saber los numeros menores como hago?

Comment: Al menos podrías haber marcado la respuesta como aceptada, @asdfg. Por respeto a quien dedica su tiempo a ayudarte gratis, porque así quien tenga la misma duda encontrará la respuesta y porque si quieres que te volvamos a ayudar, y veo que no te molestas en marcar las respuestas, me lo voy a pensar dos veces.

Comment: lo siento bro ya la marque, me ayudo un monton sera que me podrias ayudar porfavor